# Angular routing animation doesn't pass smoothly on component leave

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to do a smooth components' transition on routing with @angular/animations. When routing from '**home**' to '**about**' (just 2 for example purposes) component, everything passes just fine. The thing is, that I have some child components in about component itself. The problem is that, '**child1**' component, which is a child of about in the below example, enters with the predefined animation as it is already the part of about component, but leaves without any animation transition!

Why isn't animation applied to the child component when leaving the about component?

The example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zoh6cs